# Combinatorics geometric series for connected two-point function

Tags: symmetry, feynman-diagrams, greens-functions, propagator, self-energy

In this answer [Proof of geometric series two-point function](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/440789/) it is said:

> 3. Now what about the coefficients in front of each Feynman diagram? Due to the combinatorics/factorization involved it becomes a geometric series 
>      $$G_c~=~G_0\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\Sigma G_0)^n\tag{A}$$

How can we prove this? My main concern is the combinatorics, for example in qed the symmetry factor for connected diagrams is 1.suppose that $\Sigma=A+B+...$ are irreducible diagrams of the photon propagator.

Since symmetry factor of $G_0AG_0AG_0=1$  we should have the symmetry factor of $A=1$.The same thing for $B$.

But we also have the factor $G_0AG_0BG_0+G_0BG_0AG_0$
The only way this to work is that $G_0AG_0BG_0=-G_0BG_0AG_0$

How can I prove this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Recall

   - that the partition function $Z[J]$ is the generating functional of all$^1$ [Feynman diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_diagram);
   - that $$W_c[J]~=~\frac{\hbar}{i}\ln Z[J]$$ is the generating functional of connected Feynman diagrams, cf. the [linked cluster theorem](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/324252/2451);
   - and that the Feynman rules dictate that each such Feynman diagram should be divided by its [symmetry factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_diagram#Symmetry_factors).
2. In contrast, for a connected $n$-point correlation function $$\langle\phi^{i_1}\ldots\phi^{i_n}\rangle^c_J~=~ \left(\frac{\hbar}{i}\right)^{n-1}\frac{\delta^n W_c[J]}{\delta J_{i_1} \ldots\delta J_{i_n}},$$ the $n$ external legs are considered distinguishable, and not symmetrized. We emphasize that it does *not* contain a [$S_n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group)-symmetry factor of its $n$ external legs.
3. In particular,

   - the full propagator/connected 2-pt function $$\langle\phi\phi\rangle^c_{J=0}~=~\frac{\hbar}{i}G_c$$ from eq. (A),
   - the bare/free propagator $\frac{\hbar}{i}G_0$, and
   - the [self-energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-energy) $\frac{i}{\hbar}\Sigma$

   are *not* divided by the $\mathbb{Z}_2$-symmetry of their 2 external legs, independently of whether the propagator [is directed or undirected/has or hasn't an arrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientation_(graph_theory)).
4. Similarly, if the self-energy $$\frac{i}{\hbar}\Sigma~=~\sum_k\frac{F_k}{S_k}$$ is built from individual 1PI Feynman diagrams $F_k$ with 2 (amputated) external legs, we only divide with symmetry $S_k$ of $F_k$ as if the 2 external legs were distinguishable. Furthermore, the geometric series (A) therefore neatly generates connected Feynman diagrams weighted with appropriate symmetry factors.

References:

1. P. Etingof, *Geometry & QFT,* [MIT 2002 online lecture notes](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-238-geometry-and-quantum-field-theory-fall-2002/lecture-notes/); Chapter 3.

--

$^1$ For the perturbative expansion, see e.g. Ref. 1 or my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/270456/2451).

Comment: Where can  i find the proof of these?